# What items "fit snugly in small areas"?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

One of my villagers gave me a task about giving him a furniture good for fitting snugly into small areas. I gave him corner items but he refused them. Anyone know some items that might match the task item request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Villagers will infrequently ask the player for furniture that match certain size-based criteria.  Sometimes they will ask for situational pieces like your instance, and in other cases they will ask for items that take up as much space as a random piece of furniture that they currently own.  (For example, I've been asked to find an item that takes up as much space as a Pyramid before... 4 units of flooring in a square shape.)

Judging from the context of your villager's request, they are very likely looking for a furniture piece that takes up one unit of flooring.  Checking the size of an item is pretty straightforward: simply take it home and place it in your room! Items that take up 'one unit of flooring' will appear right in front of the player -- larger items that take up two or more units of flooring will move away from the player to fill the appropriate space.

As far as I know, villagers won't turn down any pieces of furniture that fill the space requirement they are looking for.  This is also true for bugs and fish, if you would like to unload any of those to quickly finish the task.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find the perfect furniture to give away to end the task!